# Eclipse (3.4) will not load Flex Plugin

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse

I installed Flex Builder plug in (3.2) into Eclipse 3.4. The installation had no errors, but I get this error when trying to start a new Flex Project.

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in com.adobe.flexbuilder.apollo.ui was unable to load class com.adobe.flexbuilder.apollo.ui.wizards.flex.FlexApolloProjectWizard.
com/adobe/flexbuilder/editors/common/ui/project/wizards/AbstractFlexProjectWizar d

I have tried re-installing several times, even tried the older eclipse versions.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: I haven't seen this one before.  I think you should contact Adobe Support.

Answer (score 0):

When Flex is installed on a Windows machine, it generates two versions of the Flex SDK, one in C:/Programs Files/Adobe/Flex Builder 3 Plug-in and the other in your Eclipse directory (not sure if this is true on a Mac).  I've fixed similar issues by copying missing files from the Flex Builder folder into the parallel Eclipse plug-in directory.  That would be my first guess.

If that does not work, you may have to contact Adobe.

Sometimes Flex is... terrible.  I mean absolutely awful.

Answer (score 0):

There was a major kerfluful with the fact that FlexBuilder would install correctly in Eclipse 3.4. The new Flashbuilder, for version 4 is designed to work with 3.5(galileo), I'm hoping that it will work with Helios, so I will no longer need to keep multiple Eclipse versions going. [Here's a link on how to make it work.](http://insideria.com/2009/09/fixed-an-internal-build-error.html) I just hope we don't have to keep repeating this.